# Laravel caching: database query vs routes

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5

Which of the two is better and/or provides better performance? Database caching or route caching?

If database caching cache the database results, what does route caching particularly cache?

Will implementing both improve website performance?

Answer (score 1):

This are two different concepts. Having a long routes file can take some miliseconds to load in each request. Routes are registered in the app when it boots. Caching the routes speeds up this process.
Sounds like you know what is database caching. If you are looking for the best performance you'll probably use both.